# Trying to understand the lifecycle stages of React

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am confused about the order of lifecycle stages in my React app. I have the following class:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    skip: 0
  }

}

fetchMoreArticles() {
  this.props.dispatch(fetchArticles(this.state.skip))
  this.setState({skip: (this.state.skip + 5)})
  console.log(this.state.skip); //This outputs 0 on page refresh???
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.fetchMoreArticles()
}
```

When I write to the console (see `fetchMoreArticles()`) I would expect the output to be 5 but it's 0. Could someone explain why?

**Note:** `fetchArticles()` is an ajax call using Redux

Answer (score 2):

`setState` is asynchronous. So you have to use a callback :

```
this.setState({skip: (this.state.skip + 5)}, () => {
    console.log(this.state.skip);
})
```